# Prove that for every natural number $n$ a polynomial $P(P(...(P(x))...)-Q(Q(...Q(Q(x))...)$ is divisible by a polynomial $P(x)-Q(x)$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

> Let $P$ and $Q$ be different polynomials, that satisfy $$P(Q(x))=Q(P(x))\tag1$$ for every $x$. Prove that for every natural number $n$ a polynomial $$\underbrace{P(P(...P(P}_{n\text{ times}}(x))...)-\underbrace{Q(Q(...Q(Q}_{n\text{ times}}(x))...)$$ is divisible by a polynomial $P(x)-Q(x)$.

I would like to solve this problem without using induction. The only relation that I managed to find is that $$\underbrace{P(P(...P(Q}_{n\text{ times}}(x))...)=\underbrace{Q(P(...P(P}_{n\text{ times}}(x))...)$$ it a simple conclusion from $(1)$. Any ideas how to proceed? Any help appreciated.

Comment: You'll need to use _some_ form of induction somewhere; otherwise you have no chance of proving anything about $n$-fold repetitions. The "best" you can hope for is to find an argument where the induction applies to a _simpler_ claim than your main goal ...

Comment: I see, thank you.

Comment: (1) is a very strong condition for polynomials. A difficult theorem of Ritt (1922) says there are only three nontrivial ways to achieve it, up to conjugation by a degree-1 polynomial (and in some cases root-of-unity constant factors): a) $P$ and $Q$ are both iterates of the same polynomial; b) $P$ and $Q$ are both simply powers of the unknown; c) $P$ and $Q$ are both Chebyshev polynomials of the first kind.